# Retrieve secret value from SecretManager in AWS CDK

Tags: python, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

I am creating RDS engine using AWS cdk

```
self.cluster = rds.DatabaseInstance(self, kwargs['env_name'] + "-db",
                         instance_identifier=kwargs['env_name'] + "-db",
                         database_name=kwargs['env_name'] + "DB",
                         engine=self.engine,
                         vpc=kwargs['vpc_stack'],
                         security_groups = [self.rds_sg],
                         instance_type=ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE3, ec2.InstanceSize.SMALL),
                         storage_encrypted = True,
                         storage_encryption_key = self.kms_key,
                         vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(
                             subnet_group_name=kwargs['env_name']+"-RDS"
                         )
                       )
```

self.cluster.secret returns object *aws_cdk.aws_secretsmanager.Secret*

After creation I need to create another resources with RDS host and password.

But I can not retrieve this values from  self.cluster.secret. I am tried  to use

`self.cluster.secret.secret_value_from_json('password').unsafe_unwrap()`

but i got

`{resolve:secretsmanager:arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:606097445846:secret:vtselmdbSecretFFCAA3B9-ubFyc10Ln1aV-ZM3TeQ:SecretString:password::}}.`

Can you help me? How can i get plain text password?

Comment: What leads you to believe the password is stored in there?

Comment: i see these values on the AWS console 

password    
dbname  
engine  
port    
dbInstanceIdentifier   
host    
username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I can use `self.cluster.secret.secret_value_from_json('password').unsafe_unwrap()` in another resources, not in output

Comment: its called `unsafe` for a reason. The reason you get a Resolve you posted in your question is because that value is not resolved until Cloudformation takes the template and goes to resolve it. Anywhere else its just a token representing where Cloudformation has to look to find the secret - its a security concious thing,.

Comment: Got it. But in some situation i need to resolve values before finish. For example  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73002695/how-can-i-get-parameters-from-construct-before-finishing-of-creation-stack.