# How can i get parameters from Construct before finishing of creation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Can you help me please?
I create DatabaseInstanceEngine and eks secret and want to put `db_instance_endpoint_address` to this secret

```
self.cluster.add_manifest('my-secret-env', {
      "kind": "Secret",
      "apiVersion": "v1",
      "metadata": {
        "name": "my-secret-env",
        'namespace': 'default'
      },
      "data": {
        "DATA_HOST": self._base64encode(self.db.db_instance_endpoint_address),
        
      }
    })
```

after execution I see ${Token[TOKEN.475]} instead of value
When i create SSM parameter (only for test)

```
ssm_parameter = ssm.StringParameter(self, "mySsmParameter",
                      parameter_name="mySsmParameter",
                      string_value=self.db.db_instance_endpoint_address,
                      type=ssm.ParameterType.STRING
                      )
```

I see correct value
How can i resolve this token?
`secretenv.node.add_dependency(self.db)` did not help
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
I changed python's `base64` to `Fn.base64` and problem was solved because resolve Fn.base64 tokens.
Unfortunately this way is not good for `DatabaseInstance .secret.secret_value_from_json('password').unsafe_unwrap()`

I recieve this using Customresource

Answer (score 0):

Try without self._base64encode(.....)

explain:
when you reference some value in CDK it puts a reference string in the cloudformation template and resolves the value at deploy time, when you encode this value as base64 it doesn't resolve at deploy time.

Take a look a the cloudformation template after you run synth.